# What is the best/worst/average time efficiency of the double metaphone algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I'm looking at the Double Metaphone algorithm.  I just want to calculate the efficiency class that the algorithm falls under.  Here it is in [Python](http://www.atomodo.com/code/double-metaphone/metaphone.py/view).  This is the most readable code I could find.

I'm not great an analyzing algorithms' times, but I know that the while loop in this algorithm should take the most time.  In this case, the program looks at each character in a string from left to right:

```
while pos <= last :
```

I would assume that this will take n steps, where n is the length of the string.

However, the algorithm has a LOT of 'if' and 'elif' statements inside of this loop; I don't know if they would significantly affect the time.  Could anyone step me through this?  I'd like to work out the time efficiency with summations.

To attempt to answer my own question, I think the best efficiency of it would be a string of length 1, where it has to enter as few 'if' statements as possible.  On the other hand, the worst case scenario is probably just an extremely long string.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you accidentally omitted that code you were referring to.

Comment: @David it's in the link and it's really long, so probably better it wasn't posted

Comment: At first I read this as "double metaphore algorithm" and now I'm just disappointed by what could have been

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking at every condition, this looks linear to me.  A simple rule with some exceptions below is that if/then statements don't affect the asymptotic runtime of the algorithm unless they do some sort of looping or recursion.  Everything I saw looks like constant time operations.

Here's how I would approach it if I really needed to be sure. If it's not straightforwardly dependent on the condition statement, you need to look for a few things

1. `break` statements and other things that alter the flow of control - this might lessen asymptotic time
2. Irregular modifications of the variable in the `while` or `for` statement, this might make the algorithm take more time.  Here, this would mean either `pos` or `last` get modified.

This isn't a comprehensive list, but it might aid you.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.  I don't know Python too well, but I found it to be the most readable source code for this algorithm, as there isn't a good pseudocode around.  As far as I know, nothing outside of the while loop takes more than constant time, but I wanted to make sure.  Thank you!

Comment: On a related note, I don't really understand how to input a string to this script.  The author notes this usage:  'dm(string) -> (string, string or None)'.  Being a rookie Python user, I don't understand how to run it.  I've tried 'python metaphone.py dm(stringHere)' with no luck.  My ignorance is showing.

Comment: Try the -c flag.  python -c 'print 1+1'.  Better yet, just write a script and put `import <filename without \.py>` and then write your code and run that

Comment: So something like this?  python -c 'print string' metaphone.py

Comment: @TimeBomb006 - It would be `python -c 'print dm(\"your string\")'` I would suggest learning the basic language syntax though if you plan to do more than just this